# numpy array feature called "Indexing with boolean Arrays"

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

consider following expression:

dZ[Z <= 0] = 0

This means as Z <= 0 then dz = 0
Does it mean when Z > 0 that dz = 1 ?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't. It means that all the elements of `dz` which correspond to the position where `z <= 0` , will be set to 0. As an example :

```
dz = np.array([[1, 4, 7],[2, 5, 8],[3, 6, 9]])
z = np.array([[1, 1, -1],[-1, 1, -1],[1, 1, -1]])
print(dz)
print(z)
```

yields :

```
[[1 4 7]
 [2 5 8]
 [3 6 9]]
[[ 1  1 -1]
 [-1  1 -1]
 [ 1  1 -1]]
```

and

```
dz[z<=0]=0
print(dz)
```

yields :

```
[[1 4 0]
 [0 5 0]
 [3 6 0]]
```

In the array `z`, there are four positions where `z <= 0` : `(1,3)`, `(2,1)`, `(2,3)` and `(3,3)`. Hence, the elements of `dz` at these positions are set to 0.
As you can see, the other elements are not affected.

You probably confuse the array of booleans with the array of values :

`z <= 0` is a condition. It is an array of booleans (same size than `z`) with 1 at the positions `(i,j)` where `z(i,j) <= 0` and 0 elsewhere.

`dz[z<=0]` is an array of values. This is the array of the values of `dz`, where the condition `z <= 0` is true, hence where there is a 1 in the array of booleans `z <= 0`.

Comment: Hello I do not understand 100%. You say: It doesn't. It means that all the elements of dz which correspond to the position where Z <= 0 , will be set to 0                                 But as far as I can see dz gets values True or False in stead of 0? Can you explain in litle more dept or with more example? Tnx

Comment: Ok my bad, I understand now what you're looking for. I will edit the response

Comment: This makes it already more clear for me yes, however one more thing. If I execute following z = np.array([[1, 1, -1],[-1, 1, -1],[1, 1, -1]], dtype = bool) then I have an array where everything is put on true. But you say that the condition z(i,j) <= 0 should be 1 and 0 elsewhere. So why are the -1 also put on True?

Comment: When you use np.array([[1, 1, -1],[-1, 1, -1],[1, 1, -1]], **dtype = bool**), you declare an array of booleans. By definition, when you cast an int to a bool, if the int is 0 that's `false`, otherwise its `true`. So it is normal to have `true` everywhere. Now if you do `z<=0` with `z` an array of int, it yields an array of bool with 1 where `z(i,j) <= 0` and 0 otherwise.

Comment: I mean,  "Now if you do z<=0 with z an array of int, it yields an array of bool with `true` where z(i,j) <= 0 and `false` otherwise" ;)